# Finding the minimum value of an unknown required for series to converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the minimum $p$ such that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1} $$ will converge?

My first idea was to do the direct comparison test with $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{p+1}}$$ and then do a *p*-series test on that, but I don't think that works since I can't prove that
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1} \le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{p+1}}$$

Comment: $\sqrt {n+1}\leq \sqrt2 \sqrt n$

Comment: What about the denominator? Is it possible to make a *p*-series for comparison?

Comment: Denominator:  $n+1>0$?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you should do the *limit* comparison test with $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{n^{1/2}}{n^{p+1}}=\frac{1}{n^{p+1/2}}$$
We know that this is a *p*-series that will converge for $p>1/2$.

The limit comparison test says that if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|=L$$
where $L$ is some finite number, then either both series converge or both series diverge. Let's set $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1} \hspace{1cm}b_n=\frac{1}{n^{p+1/2}}$$
When doing the division, think about the following:
$$x^{3/2}\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{x^3}\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{x^4+x^3}=\sqrt{x^4(1+1/x)}=x^2\sqrt{1+1/x}$$
We'll use a similar technique.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}}{\frac{1}{n^{p+1/2}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1} \cdot \frac{n^{p+1/2}}{1}$$
We don't need the absolute value bars since both series are positive.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1} \cdot \frac{n^{p+1/2}}{1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^{2p+1}}\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^{2p+2}+n^{2p+1}}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^{2p+2}(1+1/n)}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{p+1}\sqrt{(1+1/n)}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}$$
As $n$ goes to $\infty$, the square root just becomes $1$, so now we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{p+1}}{n^{p+1}+n+1}=1$$
due to the properties of infinite limits of rational expressions. (Numerator has same degree as denominator so limit is ratio of leading coefficients.)

So the limit comparison test proves that either both series converge or both series diverge. And since $b_n$ converges for $p>1/2$, so does $a_n$.